# Wamp server icon indicates orange color

Tags: wamp

When I start the wamp server it indicates only orange color. I tried to fix that problem but I could not to fix that. The one thing I did is below,

```
Apache->service->install service
```

cmd shows this ,

> your port 80 actually used by : server : microsoft -IIS/7.5 cannot
>   install the apache service , please stop this application and try
>   again. press enter to exit

Comment: If you are not using IIS (microsofts web server) then uninstall it or disable its services. It is much better to keep a web server on the default port 80

Comment: yes @RiggsFolly , I did that, then I could fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS server used same port as wamp server. 
 Two solutions have found.

- assign a new port to use to wamp.
- stop running IIS server

Answer (score 1):

So Uninstall wamp server and reinstall..

In the process of installing choose the different portnumber rather than 8080,

hope it will work